# QML Keys weird / buggy behavior - event sent to the wrong object

Tags: focus, qml, qt5, keyboard-events, qtquick2

I am experiencing some weird behavior when handling QML keyboard events. In this example, an object tree can be created, by selecting a tree element, the plus and minus keys should append and remove elements of the selected branch, and the spacebar should expand or contract the selected branch.

[image]

But it doesn't work as expected. While plus and minus will work on the currently active element, the spacebar will always always expand/contract the root element regardless of which element is currently selected. Oddly enough, using the mouse right button works on the correct element as expected, achieving the desired behavior. Both the spacebar and the right mouse button use practically the same code, but for some reason, using spacebar always invokes the function of the root node, not on the one currently in focus, which should be receiving keyboard events.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
UI {
    id: ui
    expanded: true

    UIList {
        model: ui.proxy.model()
    }    

    Rectangle {
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: ui.activeFocus ? "red" : "darkred"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
            onClicked: {
                if (mouse.button === Qt.LeftButton) ui.forceActiveFocus()
                else ui.expanded = !ui.expanded
            }
        }
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        switch (event.key) {
        case Qt.Key_Plus:
            ui.create()
            break
        case Qt.Key_Minus:
            ui.pop()
            break
        case Qt.Key_Space:
            ui.expanded = !ui.expanded
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out `forceActiveFocus()` gives focus not just to the particular element, but to all elements of the hierarchy as well. The event is received in the target element and then cascades down its parents until the root element.

A simple `event.accepted = true` in the event handler suffices to stop its propagation down the hierarchy.